# Converting MS Access queries to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mariadb

I'm struggling to create MariaDB SQL commands which will produce the same output as these three queries (below) which I'm currently using with an MS Access database.  My Excel VBA script calls the third SQL query command below (Hours to Heat Elecric WH) with **only** this SQL command, where the date value is substituted dynamically.  For the purposes of this question that command would look like this:

```
SELECT ElectricWH_Data.* 
FROM ElectricWH_Data
WHERE (ElectricWH_Data.Date_Reading) > #06/01/19#;
```

This is an abstract of the resulting table:

```
Date_Time       Date        Time     Max WH Out   Min WH Out
6/27/18 0:52    06/27/18    00.52    60.38        43.56
6/28/18 0:52    06/28/18    00.52    60.50        44.44
6/29/18 0:32    06/29/18    00.32    60.13        45.38
6/30/18 0:32    06/30/18    00.32    60.19        47.13
 7/1/18 0:12    07/01/18    00.12    60.50        47.56
 7/2/18 0:42    07/02/18    00.42    60.44        44.94
 7/3/18 0:42    07/03/18    00.42    60.38        46.88
```

I would like to duplicate this process but using a MariaDB database and SQL commands.  Can you assist?

By the way, I am aware that dates and date formats are handled differently in MariaDB.

Below are the SQL queries from the MS Access database.

GetTemDataByDay:

```
SELECT 
  Min(PiSolarWH.Electric_WH_Out) AS MinOfElectric_WH_Out, 
  Max(PiSolarWH.Electric_WH_Out) AS MaxOfElectric_WH_Out, 
  Format(PiSolarWH.Date_Reading,'mm/dd/yy') AS TheDay
FROM
  PiSolarWH
GROUP BY
  Format(PiSolarWH.Date_Reading,'mm/dd/yy');
```

ElectricWHData:

```
SELECT
  PiSolarWH.Date_Reading, 
  Format([PiSolarWH.Date_Reading],'mm/dd/yy') AS TheDate,
  Format([Date_Reading],'hh.mm') AS DayTime, 
  GetTempDataByDay.MaxOfElectric_WH_Out AS Expr1, 
  GetTempDataByDay.MinOfElectric_WH_Out AS Expr2
FROM
  GetTempDataByDay, PiSolarWH
WHERE 
  Format([PiSolarWH.Date_Reading],'mm/dd/yy') = [GetTempDataByDay].[TheDay] 
  AND GetTempDataByDay.MaxOfElectric_WH_Out = [PiSolarWH].[Electric_WH_Out];
```

Hours to Heat Elecric WH:

```
SELECT
  PiSolarWH.Date_Reading, 
  Format([Date_Reading],'hh.mm') AS DayTime,
  GetTempDataByDay.MaxOfElectric_WH_Out, 
  PiSolarWH.Electric_WH_Out, 
  Format([PiSolarWH.Date_Reading],'mm/dd/yy') AS Expr1
FROM
  GetTempDataByDay,
  PiSolarWH
WHERE 
  GetTempDataByDay.MaxOfElectric_WH_Out = [PiSolarWH].[Electric_WH_Out]
  AND Format([PiSolarWH.Date_Reading],'mm/dd/yy') = [GetTempDataByDay].[TheDay];
```

Comment: Are those queries populating tables, such as a make or append table query in MS Access? Seems like there is more formatting being done than necessary ... Anyway, with MySQL/MariaDB, the `[]` with table and/or column names are not needed, as the use is typically `tableName.columnName`, or just the `columnName` depending upon the query to avoid ambiguity. To format the date, like yours, would be: `DATE_FORMAT(Date_Reading, '%m/%d/%y')`  ... The time would be `TIME_FORMAT(Date_Reading, '%h.%i')`.  Unlike MS Access, date strings are surrounded with single quotes, not the `#` characters.

Comment: the query "GetTemDataByDay " is referenced in the other two queries.  I wrote those queries at least 5 years ago when I was using MS Access and classic ASP pages. They did what I wanted.  But now I trying to learn MariaDB and as an exercise to convert that old ASP SQL code into something I could run via a MariaDB setup.   I'm aware of the formatting issues between MS SQL, SQL and MariaDB.

Comment: That's fine, so what other aspects do you need to know? ... those were only overview things in the previous comment.  I have converted a few MS Access things into MySQL.

Comment: Many, many, things need changing.  No brackets, totally different date handling, etc.

Comment: I'm afraid that my question may not have been clear.  I understand the functional and formatting differences between MS SQL and MariaDB SQL, but thanks for the reminders.  I'm trying to understand if I can repeat with MariaDB the use of the stored MS Queries within an other queries or SQL statement.  For example, you will notice that "GetTemDataByDay" is referenced in both "ElectricWHData" and "Hours to Heat Elecric WH" and both  "GetTemDataByDay" and "ElectricWHData" are referenced in "Hours to Heat Elecric WH".  I don't see how to do that in MariaDB.

Comment: Folks....The answer seems to be "Views".  I was reading about temporary tables and then heard about "Views".  They work exactly like the MS Access stored queries.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out! MariaDB's stored VIEWS work like MS Access Stored Queries.  I was able to add the three MS Access queries (of course with modified syntax) to the database as stored VIEWS.  The work exacgtly like those in MS Access.  Here is one example:

```
CREATE VIEW GetTempDataByDay AS
SELECT 
  date_reading,
  Min(temps.Electric_WH_Out) AS MinOfElectric_WH_Out, 
  Max(temps.Electric_WH_Out) AS MaxOfElectric_WH_Out, 
  date(temps.Date_Reading) AS TheDay
FROM
  temps
GROUP BY
  date(temps.Date_Reading);
```

Which is then used in the other two VIEWS which I created to duplicate the MS Access stored queries.

Thanks for your time....RDK